# Can I write and deploy smart contracts using Jaxx wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am quite new to Ethereum development . I would like to know if i can create new smart contracts using solidity programming language and deploy them to the network using Jaxx wallet . Right now I have downloaded Ethereum wallet from github for this purpose , but it takes a long time as it downloads all the blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only transfer crypto currency with Jaxx wallet. Although [myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) provides a function to deploy contracts without syncing all the node data.

MyEtherWallet doesn't compile the contract code for you. It takes in the byte code for contract deployment. You can use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.12+commit.194ff033.js) for getting the bytecode of your contract.

Comment: Just want to point out that you _can_ send pre-signed transaction data to simply call a contract via Jaxx as of 0.0.15 (https://decentral.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217877408-How-do-I-send-to-a-smart-contract-), although that doesn't seem very efficient a setup.